# Special units of the cyclotomic number field of an odd prime order $l$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th  root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $k$ be a rational integer not divisible by $l$.
How would you prove that $(1 - \zeta^k)/(1 - \zeta)$ is a unit of $A$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174693/decomposition-of-l-in-a-subfield-of-a-cyclotomic-number-field-of-an-odd-prime) is a related question.

Comment: I tried to compute the norm of it.

Comment: That is doable but unnecessary. It will be easier to try to write the inverse as an element of $A$.

Comment: @MakotoKato Can you show that $ (1-\zeta^k)/(1-\zeta) \in A $ ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think N($1 - \zeta^k$) = N($1 - \zeta$) is clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to verify that this is indeed an element of $A$, and also because it hints at a way of showing that your element is a unit in that ring: a very old identity tells you that
\[
\frac{1 - \zeta^k}{1 - \zeta} = 1 + \zeta + \dots + \zeta^{k - 1}.
\]
Since $k$ is prime to $l$, you can find an integer $k'$ such that $kk' \equiv 1 \bmod l$. Then writing
\[
\frac{1 - \zeta}{1 - \zeta^k} = \frac{1 - \zeta^{kk'}}{1 - \zeta^k}
\]
should help quite a bit. These are called, somewhat confusingly, the [cyclotomic units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_unit). A book on Iwasawa theory should talk about them quite a bit.

Comment: I think I learned this from a book [Washington, maybe?] — I definitely am not clever enough to have discovered it independently.