# Show that $\frac{1-\zeta_p^k}{1-\zeta_p^j}$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a prime. For $1 \leq j,k \leq p-1$, show that
$$\frac{1-\zeta_p^k}{1-\zeta_p^j}$$
is invertible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$.

First, I wanted to show that $\frac{1-\zeta_p^k}{1-\zeta_p^j} \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$ but I did not even manage to do that.
I tried to use that $1+\zeta_p + \zeta_p^2 + \cdots + \zeta_p^{p-2} + \zeta_p^{p-1} = 0$ to deduce that
$$1-\zeta_p^k = \zeta_p + \zeta_p^2 + \cdots + \zeta_p^{k-1} + \zeta_p^{k+1} + \cdots + \zeta_p^{p-1}$$
and
$$1-\zeta_p^j = \zeta_p + \zeta_p^2 + \cdots + \zeta_p^{j-1} + \zeta_p^{j+1} + \cdots + \zeta_p^{p-1},$$
but then I did not see how to simplify $\frac{1-\zeta_p^k}{1-\zeta_p^j}$.

Comment: Hint: There is an integer $m$ such that $mj\equiv k\pmod p$. BTW I'm fairly sure that this has been covered in an earlier question here.

Comment: I guess $\zeta_p$ is a $p$-th root of unity?

Comment: There are several older posts dealing with more advanced properties of cyclotomic units. Do peruse them! [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174919/11619) explains how to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @JyrkiLahtonen . It took a while but I figured out the evidence. $\frac{1-\zeta_p^k}{1-\zeta_p^j} = \frac{1-(\zeta_p^j)^m}{1-\zeta_p^j} = 1 +  \zeta_p^j + \cdots + (\zeta_p^{j})^{m-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p].$
@ Bernard Yes this is correct. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prove that the cyclotomic integers $\frac{\zeta_p^r - 1}{\zeta_p^s - 1}$, with $\ p\nmid rs$, are units?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724820/how-can-i-prove-that-the-cyclotomic-integers-frac-zeta-pr-1-zeta-ps-1)