# Which primes ramify when adjoining roots of a unit?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

1) For ANF $K$, if $\zeta_n, u\in\cal O_k^\times$, are there any primes that ramify in $k(\sqrt[n]{u})/k$?

2) is the HCF composed solely of all such extensions, or are there others?

Long story: Let $k$ be an algebraic number field.  I am looking for primes that ramify in arbitrary extensions $L/k$.  I decompose the extension $L/k$ into smaller extensions, which are easier to analyze:

- A number of cyclotomic extensions of $k$.  If $q^n$-th root of unity is adjoined, then $q$ is the only prime of $L$ that can ramify. (Proof: see [Ramified primes in a cyclotomic number field of a prime power order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175283/ramified-primes-in-a-cyclotomic-number-field-of-a-prime-power-order))
- A number of roots of non-units of $\cal O$.  If we are adjoining $\sqrt[n]{p}$, then the only ramified primes are those dividing the ideal generated by $p$ in $\cal O$ (I think this one's an if-and-only-if), and also over $n$.
- A number of roots of units of $\cal O$.  Once again, the primes over $n$ can ramify; how do I find out whether or not they do? [partially answered by Lubin; edited to reflect mercio's answer]  Are there others that ramify?
- Also, is the Hilbert Class Field composed chiefly of adjoining roots of units of $\cal O$?

References are fine also.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the extension $k(\sqrt[n]{u})/k$, only primes dividing $n$ can ramifiy. Whether they do depends on congruences of $u$ modulo powers of prime ideals above $n$. You will find what you need in Hecke's book (Lectures on the Theory of Algebraic Numbers, § 39).
2. If $k$ contains the appropriate roots of unity, then you get the Hilbert class field by adjoining the $n$-th root of an element for which the ideal it generates is an $n$-th power. If $k$ does not have the necessary roots of unity you will have to adjoin them first.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out by now, but +1 for the reference.

Comment: Err...  Sorry, where in that book?  I am pretty familiar with all the material in the first 5 chapters; the rest seems to be mostly analytic methods.  Alternatively, what happens if, say, $u=1$?

Answer (score 1):

When you adjoin an $n$th root, primes over $n$ will often ramify. For example consider adding a square root of $3$ to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Is there a way to determine whether or not they ramify?  Also, can there be any others?

Comment: It depends on a congruence of what you are taking a root of, modulo something. Also, Hilbert class fields are not as easy when you don't have the corresponding root of unity in the field

Comment: Sorry, your answer is vague.  Modulo what?  Root of unity corresponding to what?  Maybe you can give a reference instead?

Comment: Sorry, i am on mobile and it's hard to do anything. I actually remember a related question to each of your questions, one about adding fourth roots in Q(i), one about building a cubic HCF without having a cube root of 1

Comment: Well, I think that if the $p$-th roots of unity are in the ground field, adjoining the $p$th root of $a$ will be unramified at the prime $p$ if $a\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$.